# How to pass information through a "pipeline" of immutable types

Tags: c++, c++11, immutability

I have some code that deals with receiving messages, parsing them, and handling them. I'm interested in making the types immutable to make it easier to reason about them. Here's a stripped down example:

```
class ReceivedMessage {
public:
  ReceivedMessage(const string& message)
    : m_message(message)
  { }
  const string& GetReceivedMessage() const { return m_message; }
  chrono::steady_clock::time_point GetReceivedAt() const { return m_receivedAt; }

private:
  const string m_message;
  const chrono::steady_clock::time_point m_receivedAt = chrono::steady_clock::now();
}

class ParsedMessage {
public:
  ParsedMessage(const ReceivedMessage& rm)
    : m_json(ParseMessage(rm.GetReceivedMessage()))
  { }
  const string& GetJson() const { return m_json; }

private:
  const json_t m_json;
}

class HandledMessage {
public:
  HandledMessage(const ParsedMessage& pm)
    : m_result(HandleMessage(pm))
  { }
  const string& GetResult() const { return m_result; }

private:
  const string m_result;
}
```

... and so on. This works fine, but at the end of the "pipeline", a response needs to be sent. To form the response, attributes from the first type (e.g., `m_receivedAt`) are needed.

I'm not sure of the best/right way to pass those early attributes through to the final type. Here are my ideas:

- Inheritance seems simple, but my peers say I should favor composition over inheritance.
- Each type could hold a copy of the preceding message type (i.e., ParsedMessage would hold a ReceivedMessage) and delegate calls for information from the earlier types to it, so ParsedMessage would have an additional method like `chrono::steady_clock::time_point GetReceivedAt() const { return m_parentMessage.GetReceivedAt(); }`. This feels verbose, and there's a lot of repetition if information needs to be passed from the first type to the last.
- Each message type could provide access to each of its parent message types, so to get `m_receivedAt` from a HandledMessage, it might look like `handledMessage.GetReceivedMessage().GetReceivedAt();`. This puts the burden of knowing which message type contains a particular attribute on the caller, though. I'm not sure that's something they need to deal with.

Comment: Can you store these extra attributes into other struct. Your pipeline seems to work only on a part of your structure, so split structure might help (one which use pipeline, the other which is pass as-is).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a compound type which can hold all information you need, where each stage in the pipeline simply adds values to it. The compound type would have to be mutable, but the values in it don't have to. E.g. wrap a `std::map<PropertyType, std::any>` in a class which provides only `const` getters. Then add all revelant new information to it at each stage and return this object instead of the `string`.

Comment: This is kind of what the code I'd like to replace is like. These messages are passed through lots of different classes, through a queue, and other stuff. It can be difficult to determine if a "message" at some point has been parsed, or handled, or has this attribute or that one. My goal was to give clarity about what has and hasn't been done with a message by using immutable types.

Comment: In that case, I'd simply use inheritance.

Comment: @Jay Or you could look into mixins aka the decorator pattern, which do a kind of inheritance by template arguments.

Comment: But isn't the downside that each time your message is processed by a stage it gets copied? I guess you could pimpl and move to reduce that overhead. The mixin template thing can work, but can generate a lot of internal code duplication, especially if your pipeline is not linear.